# Dropdown Button became dead when scrolling due to the appearance of the keyboard

Tags: flutter, keyboard, dropdown

I made a sign up screen containing a field of type DropDownButton, it contains the list of user types. and it works well, but when I click any other field and keyboard appears, the screen scroll up, and the DropDownButton became dead

- Before Keyboard appears

[image]

- After the keyboard appears

[image]

Comment: please add your dropdown part code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it is very strange

I changed the code I was already using and wrote a new code, the new code works perfectly

it seems to me that the old code works well on a previous version, this code I took it from the net>

its problem that it works well but sometimes when scrolling it doesn't work well

This is the new code I used

```
class ComboBoxFieldBlue extends StatefulWidget {
  List comboList;
  MainAxisAlignment alignment;
  double margin;

  ComboBoxFieldBlue({this.comboList, this.alignment, this.margin});

  @override
  _ComboBoxFieldBlueState createState() => new _ComboBoxFieldBlueState();
}

class _ComboBoxFieldBlueState extends State<ComboBoxFieldBlue> {
  String selectedValue;
  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      selectedValue = widget.comboList[0];
    });
    print(selectedValue);
    super.initState();
  }

  void changedDropDownItem(String item) {
    setState(() {
      selectedValue = item;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        border:
            Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.blue, style: BorderStyle.solid),
      ),
      child: DropdownButton(
        isExpanded: true,
        value: selectedValue,
        items: widget.comboList.map((listItem) {
          return DropdownMenuItem(value: listItem, child: Text(listItem));
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (item) {
          changedDropDownItem(item);
        },
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        elevation: 10,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```